# 'Outstanding publication commitments' meaning?

Tags: research-process, application

I'm applying for research funds and, while filling in the application and all the expenses, I came upon a field called 'Outstanding publication commitments (Please list, continuing on a separate sheet if necessary)'.

Does this mean that I should write my engagement in publishing academic papers? And before you answer, just a little info: I'm asking because I just finished my Bachelor degree and I don't have much experience in publishing (I only published one paper that is in print). However, I have experience with organizing conferences (as part of the organizing team) and I also gave two presentations on scientific conferences. Should I list this?

Comment: It might be easier to figure this out if we could see the context.  How about providing a link to the form?

Comment: You mention expenses - might this be a question about anticipated publishing costs? It's pretty common for a year or more to elapse between submission of a paper & actually paying the fees, and this sort of committed-but-unpaid cost can be a headache to manage. Agree it would be easier with the form for context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe "outstanding" here means "not yet completed".  However, I'm not sure whose commitment it's talking about, yours or the publisher's.  One interpretation is that it's asking whether you have committed to publishing anything that you haven't published yet (such as results from previous grants); another is that it's asking you to list papers that have been accepted for publication but are not yet in print.  I'd guess that it's the former, because it seems like a somewhat obscure way to ask for the latter, but I doubt anyone could say with any certainty without knowing more details.

Either way, this is probably not the right place to list your publications or related achievements such as conference organization or presentations.

Comment: Thank you for the info. The field is located just under the field for my personal information (Name, address etc.). I would also guess that it is about mine commitment.